# Why is the local puma web server returning a different error code from production?

Tags: puma

In development, when a POST to an api that is hosted on a puma server has a query string that is too long, I receive a 400 error code, which means 'Bad request'.  However, in production, on Heroku, it does return an error code of 414, which is more specific (and useful).

Why is it returning different error in development and production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is not due to Puma, but being caused by Cloudflare which is intercepting excessive length query strings.